# Put .txt file in a textarea

Tags: javascript, file, input

I have this textarea:

```
<input id="inputOuvrirFichier" type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" name="files[]" accept=".txt">
```

I need to put the contents of a .txt file into this textarea.
This is my function :

```
function handleFiles(file){
document.getElementById("titre").click();
console.log(file);}
```

How can i get the text contain in the file please ? (Javascript)
Thanks.

Comment: You're probably going to want to read the file on the server (with PHP) first and return it via AJAX.

Comment: can use [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) in modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

JS, have not access to local on ur server, only throw ajax-request:

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                $('#inputOuvrirFichier').text(allText)
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i don't understand how it work, can you explain me please ?

Comment: U make request to server (XMLHttpRequest) to ur file, then i read it when file 'load'. rawFile - request. rawFile.responseText = result of request.

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/PROJET-SKI/[object%20FileList]. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." I can't use it localy ?

Comment: U have to use path to ur webserver ( like localhost:3000/public/file.txt )

Comment: Have u webserver on ur local machine? MAMP? Apache? something like that, or u just open .html file in browser?

Comment: if u call readTextFile('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148634/put-txt-file-in-a-textarea/29148706#29148706') - u get text with THAT page =-)  all what u need - path to file at web, or ur local webmachine

Comment: whats ur OS ? mac, linux, windows?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

```js
function handleFiles(files) {
  var i = 0;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    i++;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += this.result;
    if (i < files.length)
      reader.readAsText(files[i])
  };
  reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input id="inputOuvrirFichier" type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" name="files[]" accept=".txt" multiple="">
<div id="result"></div>
```